# Facebook App Submission Optimized Sharing to Messenger

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-messenger

I'm attempting to submit my app to Facebook for review but it was rejected because I don't have a Facebook login.

My app uses Facebook Messenger to share content with friends so I have no need for a Facebook login. I need to submit for review because the attachment I'm sending through Messenger will be unavailable until the app has been approved. I've considered submitting "Optimized Sharing to Messenger" but I do know know if it'll make the Messenger attachments available.